# css selector for first element inside a div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am new to CSS and have to style a `<span>` which is this situation:

```
<div class="ui-select-container ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
  <div class="ui-select-match">
    <span class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to target the `<span>` to change its width? I tried this:

```
div .ui-select-container > span .class ui-select-toggle{
  width: 60%;
}
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    div > .ui-select-match > span {
     width:60%;
     display:block;
}
```

hope will help

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```
.ui-select-container.ui-select-bootstrap.dropdown.ng-valid.ng-touched.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse > .ui-select-match > span.ui-select-toggle {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/7geurhvL/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/7geurhvL/)

It looks as though you were targeting the wrong child selector for the `span`... In addition, you don't need to specify the word `class` when declaring a CSS style, just need to use the following: `span.ui-select-toggle`

The `.` denotes the classname...

Answer (score 0):

You are targenting a div element that have a child with class `ui-select-container` a direct children span and a child of **type** `ui-select-toggle` with **class** `class`.

You don't want this.

Space are importants if you want to target a span with a class you must write them without any space, a space mean `child of` and don't forget the point to target a class.

Try:

```
div.ui-select-container span.ui-select-toggle{
  width: 60%;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
div.ui-select-container > div.ui-select-match > span.ui-select-toggle{
  width: 60%;
}
```

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

Use like this it will work

```
  .ui-select-container .ui-select-toggle {
   width: 60%;
 }
```

check this link https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/